# Synchronizing twinx y-axis based on two lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

My end goal is to create a graph that quickly communicates that two data points are between their respective bounds. I could instead of having this information on one graph, create two separate graphs; the chart the data and illustrate the bounds with horizontal lines. If I could have it so that this basic function is done with one graph, it would be much more elegant.

Is there some method I can use to sync the two `y-axes` so that a certain value `A1` on `y-axis 1` and `A2` on `y-axis 2` appear on the same place vertically within the graph, while at the same time, ensuring that another certain value `B1` on `y-axis 1` and `B2` on `y-axis 2`appears on a separate distinct place vertically within the graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

### Generate linear data
Temp = 20
pH = 6
DataCopy = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': [], 'pH': [], 'Time': []})
for i in range(10):
    DataTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    DataCopy = DataCopy.append({'Temp': Temp, 'pH': pH, 'Time': DataTime}, ignore_index=True)
    Temp += (-0.5)
    pH   += (0.2)

### Plot data unto graph w/ double y-axis
sns.lineplot(data=DataCopy, x='Time', y='pH', color = 'red', label = 'Temp')
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=DataCopy, x='Time', y='Temp', color = 'blue', label = 'pH', ax=ax2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How this implementation would look if done on separate graphs:

[image: How this implementation would look if done on separate graphs]

Desired effect:

[image: Desired effect]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to align two positions on the left axis with two positions on the right axis.

The following approach measures the distance factor of the lower limit vs the two lines, for both axes.  Then it applies the largest factor to the axis with the lowest factor.  The analog happens for the upper limit of the axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
ph_low, ph_high = 7, 9
temp_low, temp_high = 12, 18

data_copy = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': np.random.normal(0.04, 0.4, 100).cumsum() + 10,
                          'pH': np.random.normal(0.02, 0.2, 100).cumsum() + 6,
                          'Time': pd.date_range('20211211 08:00:00', freq='1min', periods=100)})

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data=data_copy, x='Time', y='pH', color='red', label='Temp')
ax1.axhline(ph_low, color='red', ls=(0, (5, 5, 0)))
ax1.axhline(ph_high, color='red', ls=(0, (5, 5, 0)))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=data_copy, x='Time', y='Temp', color='blue', label='pH', ax=ax2)
ax2.axhline(temp_low, color='blue', ls=(0, (0, 5, 5)))
ax2.axhline(temp_high, color='blue', ls=(0, (0, 5, 5)))

handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend_.remove()
ax2.legend(handles=handles1 + handles2, labels=labels1 + labels2)

ymin1, ymax1 = ax1.get_ylim()
ymin2, ymax2 = ax2.get_ylim()

fymin1 = (ph_low - ymin1) / (ph_high - ph_low)
fymin2 = (temp_low - ymin2) / (temp_high - temp_low)
if fymin1 < fymin2:  # move ymin1 using fymin2
    ymin1 = ph_low - fymin2 * (ph_high - ph_low)
else:  # move ymin2 using fymin1
    ymin2 = temp_low - fymin1 * (temp_high - temp_low)

fymax1 = (ymax1 - ph_high) / (ph_high - ph_low)
fymax2 = (ymax2 - temp_high) / (temp_high - temp_low)
if fymax1 < fymax2:  # move ymax1 using fymax2
    ymax1 = ph_high + fymax2 * (ph_high - ph_low)
else:  # move ymax2 using fymax1
    ymax2 = temp_high + fymax1 * (temp_high - temp_low)

ax1.set_ylim(ymin1, ymax1)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin2, ymax2)

plt.show()
```

[image: aligning twinx axes on two lines]